# How do I bound the integrals for the probability density function?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, density-function

probability density function is given by $f(x_1,x_2)=(-1.5)(1-x_2)$ if $0 \leq x_1 \leq x_2 \leq 2$.

I need to find $P(x_1\leq 0.75, x_2 \geq 0.5)$. I'm not sure how to bound the double integral.

Is it maybe $\int_{0.5}^2 \int_0^{0.75}$ ?

I'm unsure mostly because $x_1 \leq x_2$, but the integral bounds above leave room for overlap.

Comment: Probability density function $5(1-x_2)$ is not valid for $0 \leq x_1 \leq x_2 \leq 2$.

Comment: My bad, I must've accidentally deleted the '-1.', I have fixed it now.

Comment: It is still not valid. Take $x_2 = 0$ for example.

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about finding the correct coefficient value then. Any hints?

Comment: OK edit your question to also state the original pdf that was given as $k (1-x_2)$. It is valid if you have two different values of $k$ for $x_2 \leq 1$ and $x_2 \geq 1$.

Comment: As there is change in sign at $x_2 = 1$, you cannot integrate straight between $0 \leq x_2 \leq 2$ to find coefficient. That will not give you a valid pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is ambiguous and pdf is valid if you choose different $k$ for $y \leq 1$ and $y \geq 1$.

Probability density function $f(x, y) = k (1-y), 0 \leq x \leq y \leq 2$

i) For $0 \leq y \leq 1$

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_0^y k (1-y) \ dx \ dy = \frac{k}{6}$

ii) For $1 \leq y \leq 2$

$\displaystyle \int_1^2 \int_0^y k(1-y) \ dx \ dy = -\frac{5k}{6}$

That leads to two different pdf's for $0 \leq y \leq 1$ (with $k = 1$) and for $1 \leq y \leq 2$ (with $k = -1$). It could have been simply defined as $|1-y|$.

[image]

To find probability for the shaded region, split the integral as,

$\displaystyle \int_{0.5}^{0.75} \int_0^y (1-y) \ dx \ dy + \int_{0.75}^{1} \int_0^{0.75} (1-y) \ dx \ dy + \int_{1}^{2} \int_0^{0.75} (y-1) \ dx \ dy$

Answer (score 0):

Before you do anything, fix the density function definition.  It is negative for $x_2 \lt 1$.

You would have to split up the integral into two parts.  $\int\limits_{.5}^{.75}\int\limits_0
^{x_2}f(x_1,x_2)dx_1dx_2+\int\limits_{.75}^{2}\int\limits_0
^{.75}f(x_1,x_2)dx_1dx_2$

Comment: I was originally given $k(1-x_2)$ and solved $\int_0^2 \int_0^{x_2} k(1-x_2)=-\frac{2}{3}k=1$ to get that $k=-\frac{3}{2}$. How should I be going about this differently?

Comment: $k(1-x_2)$ has $k\gt 0$ when $0\le x_2\le 1$ or $k\lt 0$ for $1\le k_2\le 2$.  You can't have both.  The original statement is wrong.

Comment: If the original statement is wrong does that make it unsolvable?

Comment: Also, assuming the function definition were correct, then I would just split up and solve the integral as you gave above?